# References to a non-exported class are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have recently upgraded the angular project from custom webpack configuration to angular-cli. Everything working as expected when I run `ng serve` but `ng build --prod` giving below error.

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

`looger.ts`

```js
class Message {
    static show(name: string) {
        return (ref?: any, ...parameters: any[]): void => {
            //aadditional code
        };
    }
}

class Options {
    static level: string[] = ['error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'log', 'dir'];
    static moduleNames: string[] = [];
    static set(level: string[], moduleNames?: string[]) {
        //aadditional code
    }
}

export const Log = {
    error: Message.show('error'),
    warn:  Message.show('warn'),
    info:  Message.show('info'),
    debug: Message.show('debug'),
    log:   Message.show('log'),
    dir:   Message.show('dir'),
    options: {
        set: Options.set
    }
};
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
import {  Log as log } from 'logger';

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: log, useValue: log }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: are you able to understand part of the error message?

Comment: Sorry @Jota.Toledo not able too.

Comment: Does the error go away if you export `Message` and `Options` classes?

Comment: Just now I have changed getting a different error. https://imgur.com/a/KZPWlNW

Answer (score 1):

The error is **exporting**.
 so guys use export keyword in front of **class Message** .

hope this will remove your error during prod or aot build.